# Syntactic meaning of the space between the map key type and the value type

Tags: dictionary, go, syntax

An online example of Go I am following has the following syntax for a map type as a parameter in a function:

`func (contact *Contact) Validate() (map[string] interface{}, bool) {`

What does the space between map[string] and interface mean? I can't find any other examples defining a map with a space there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything. It doesn't matter if you leave space(s) there or not, the code is the same. Always use `gofmt` to avoid dis-ambiguity.

[Spec: Tokens:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Tokens)

> Tokens form the vocabulary of the Go language. There are four classes: *identifiers*, *keywords*, *operators and punctuation*, and *literals*. ***White space*, formed from spaces (U+0020), horizontal tabs (U+0009), carriage returns (U+000D), and newlines (U+000A), is ignored except as it separates tokens that would otherwise combine into a single token.** Also, a newline or end of file may trigger the insertion of a semicolon. While breaking the input into tokens, the next token is the longest sequence of characters that form a valid token.

The map type: `map[string]interface{}` is made up of tokens, and a *white space* at the position in question: `map[string] interface{}` is simply ignored because the tokens it separates (`]` and `interface` would not combine into a single token if the space wouldn't be there.